How can I elegantly put a big constant matrix without it being basically unreadable?
I'm writing a compiler project for school and I need to put a table of precalculated values into my code. The problem is that it is unreadable. How should I approach this problem?
So far I'm doing it by creating a const int matrix[13][13] and commenting every element with what it means, but it is so long that one line isn't visible without it being split.
edit: this is what it currently looks like:
const Table_contents_T table[13][13] = {
    /* + */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value,
     /* i */ precalculated_value, /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* - */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* * */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* / */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* == */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* <,>,<=,... */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* <and_or> */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* ! */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* ( */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* ) */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* i */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value, /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value,
     /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value, /* ! */ precalculated_value,
     /* ( */ precalculated_value, /* ) */ precalculated_value,
     /* i */ precalculated_value, /* b */ precalculated_value,
     /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* b */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

    /* $ */
    {/* + */ precalculated_value, /* - */ precalculated_value,
     /* * */ precalculated_value, /* / */ precalculated_value,
     /* == */ precalculated_value,
     /* <,>,<=,... */ precalculated_value, /* <and_or> */ precalculated_value,
     /* ! */ precalculated_value, /* ( */ precalculated_value,
     /* ) */ precalculated_value, /* i */ precalculated_value,
     /* b */ precalculated_value, /* $ */ precalculated_value},

};


I'd put the comment after the value and use // to comment to not have some automatic formatter mess it up afterwards: example

Or perhaps, use designated initializers: example

Maybe consider making your pre-calculation step output a valid C excerpt... and then const Table_contents_T table[13][13] = { / #include "excerpt.c.inc" // output from create_excerpt.c / };

i would rather suggest you to move the array in a resource file (normal txt or binary) then parse it into your array.

If it's calculated values then why not write a gen-table.c file that is readable and calculates those values and then outputs the unreadable table. You then compile the generated file and it's readability is irrelevant, it's just a cache so you don't have to calculate the values on every program start. What is important is that gen-table.c is readable.

Do you have an enumeration for the numbers 0..12 used as indexes for the table?  (If not, why not?)  Then you can replace the comments with "designations", using designated initializers:
const Table_Contents_T table[13][13] =
{
    [EN_PLUS]   = { [EN_PLUS]   = precalculated_value_0_0,
                    [EN_MINUS]  = precalculated_value_0_1,
                    …
                    [EN_DOLLAR] = precalculated_value_0_12,
                  },
    [EN_MINUS]  = { [EN_PLUS]   = precalculated_value_1_0,
                    [EN_MINUS]  = precalculated_value_1_1,
                    …
                    [EN_DOLLAR] = precalculated_value_1_12,
                  },
    …
    [EN_DOLLAR] = { [EN_PLUS]   = precalculated_value_12_0,
                    [EN_MINUS]  = precalculated_value_12_1,
                    …
                    [EN_DOLLAR] = precalculated_value_12_12,
                  },
};

You have multiple options on the layout, but aligning the enumeration values and the equals signs would make the code reasonably readable.  Beyond them being precalculated values, it isn't clear what the precalculated values look like — are they numbers, elements of another enumeration, an expression, or something else?  The main concern is whether the precalculated values have a nearly uniform length or whether they have wildly differing lengths.
Designated initializers were added to C99.  You should not be using any older standard (i.e. C90) any more, a quarter century later.  C23 has finally been released as ISO/IEC 9899:2024.

Or in case of huge initializer lists, once could also show all of the initializers into a macro so you get [EN_PLUS] = EN_PLUS_INIT, one-liners. And then one can go dig into the macro when interested in the details. Which is of course only a good idea in cases where it actually increases readability.
